# How to replace primary key with new column with autogenerated values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have a table `merchants` with the next columns: `name, program_id, program_name`.
The current primary key is `name + program_id`

What I need to do is to add a new column `id`, fill it in with autogenerated values (preferably uuid or something like that) and make it a new primary key.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER table merchants DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

if your database engine is innodb,I suggest you use auto increment integer as primary key,not uuid,because primary key in innodb is clustered index.Auto increment primaryk key can reduce page splitting.

> Notice that not only does it take longer to insert the rows with the UUID primary key,but the resulting indexes are quite a bit bigger. Some of that is due to the larger primary key, but some of it is undoubtedly due to page splits and resultant fragmentation as well.

and the cons of using onsequentially primary key:

- The destination page might have been flushed to disk and removed from the caches,or might not have ever been placed into the caches, in which case InnoDB will have to find it and read it from the disk before it can insert the new row. This causes a lot of random I/O.
- When insertions are done out of order, InnoDB has to split pages frequently to make room for new rows. This requires moving around a lot of data, and modifying at least three pages instead of one.
- Pages become sparsely and irregularly filled because of splitting, so the final data is fragmented.

If you want to learn more about primary key's influence on page splitting or page merging your can visit [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/10/innodb-page-merging-and-page-splitting/)